# Why does the iptables connection limit not work?

Tags: iptables

this is my iptables, everything works fine, except that these IP's with more than 20 connection wont get blocked.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X

iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6606 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 3 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6624 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 4 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6610 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6610 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 6 -i eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 7 -i eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 8 -i eth0 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j DROP

iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 6606 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 3 -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 6624 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 4 -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 6610 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 5 -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 6610 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 6 -o eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 7 -o eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 8 -o eth0 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j DROP

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

What's wrong? Why does connection limit not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accepting connections without a `connlimit` specification before the `connlimit` `DROP` rule is set.

Try putting the `DROP` rule above all the others or specify a `--connlimit-upto` inside each one of your `ACCEPT` rules. e.g.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6606 \
-m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED \
-m connlimit --connlimit-upto 20 -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 4 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: --connlimit-below doesn't exist

Comment: @DarkOne Correct.  I forgot that wasn't the inverse extension to `connlimit-above`.  It is actually, `--connlimit-upto`.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually which connection you wanted to limit here. SSH or HTTP or HTTPS or TELNET.

In the below rule, just replace the port 80 with 22 for SSH and 23 for TELNET, so it should work.

> iptables –I INPUT  -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW  -m
>   connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j REJECT --reject-with
>   icmp-admin-prohibited

Also, in some of the recent kernel the connlimit module is removed, so either you have to patch up the module inside the kernel or use the hashlimit module for restricting the connections. Hashlimit module is more stronger and flexible that connlimit module.

The below rule will limit to the 20 connections per min for the corresponding destination ip.

> iptables -A INPUT-p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW  -m hashlimit
>   --hashlimit-name \ HTTP_LIMIT  –hashlimit 20/day--hashlimit-burst  1   --hashlimit-mode dstip -j ACCEPT

For more explanation, refer http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAW.

Comment: how do you restrict the total number of connections with `hashlimit`, irrespectively of when they were created?